# Wordpress custom post not saving images in custom meta box

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, custom-post-type

Im trying to create a custom post type with only 4 images, but I'm having some trouble.
It was saving, but I made some changes and now I don't think it is even doing that. (No, it isn't uploading/saving at all.)

Another problem is that even though I am storing the url its receiving just the file name.
I have been searching extensively (apart from some other basic info, this is all of the work I have done today) and most of the answers I find are different, and don't work anyway.

I have looked up all the functions in the codex, and understand them all and I cannot for the life of me work out what is wrong.
if you would like, please message me I would be happy to send you the wp username and password so that you can look at the admin. (It is on a staging site at the moment)

Thanks so much, Billy

```
<?php add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'bwd_project',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' ),
                'add_new' => 'Add new Project',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Project',
                'new_item' => 'New Project',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Project',
                'search_items' => 'Search Projects',
                'not_found' => 'No Projects found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Projects found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Project'
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'my_admin' );

function my_admin(){
    add_meta_box( 'project_meta_box',
        'New Project',
        'display_project_meta_box',
        'bwd_project',
        'normal','high' 
    );
}

function display_project_meta_box() {
    global $post;  
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;  
    $project = get_post_custom($post->ID);  
    $logo = $project["logo"][0];  
    $img1 = $project["img1"][0];  
    $img2 = $project["img2"][0];  
    $img3 = $project["img3"][0];

    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <?php print_r($project); ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Project logo</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="logo" value="<?php echo $logo; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Image 1</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Image 2</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Image 3</strong></td>
        </tr>       

        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $img1; ?>" /></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $img2; ?>" /></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $img3; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="img2" value="<?php echo $img2; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="img1" value="<?php echo $img1; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="img3" value="<?php echo $img3; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>


    </table> <?php

}

add_action('save_post', 'save_project_link');  
function save_project_link(){  
    global $post;  
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){  
        return $post_id;  
    }else{   

        if (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
            $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
            $upload = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['logo'], $upload_overrides);
            if (!isset($upload['error'])) {

                update_post_meta($post->ID, "logo", $upload['url']);
            }
        }
    }
} 




?>
```

EDIT:Changed a few unimportant things in my code.

also, for bonus love, can anyone tell me an easy way to save the image (4 times) or do I have to do it all separately?

Comment: Clearly the problem is in the save_post part, and I found that there was an error in the upload that was preventing `wp_update_metadata()`.
I used `wp_update_metadata($post->ID, 'logo', $upload);` to get the error, which contained "a:1:{s:5:"error";s:24:"Invalid form submission.";}", but I can't think why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I feel that this is lacking. First you need to add an input type hidden for the field you would like to display, more or less like this:

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';
```

If I was you and if you are running on PHP 5.3 I would use Jeffrey Way's custom posts that come with metaboxes and taxonomies already built in and you just create the instance variables for each custom post. It makes it much faster to deploy the site. Have a go at this:

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Easy-WordPress-Custom-Post-Types

Comment: Why do I need a hidden input and what does it do? and what does `wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__))` do?
also, I'm trying to do as much of this myself as I can, so that I can learn as much as possible.

Comment: It's to verify that indeed the display came from the user with the proper authorization.

Btw if you want more on custom posts, I also recommend taking a look at this:

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/how-to-create-meta-box-wordpress-post.html